# Why does`sudo su -` still try to execute terminator?

Tags: command-line, sudo, terminator

I've recently had a problem with the shell-emulator terminator which lead me to uninstall it. Now when I type

```
sudo su -
```

I get the following response:

```
Cannot execute /usr/bin/terminator: No such file or directory
```

Previously I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove terminator
sudo apt-get purge terminator
rm -r ~/.config/terminator
```

also changed:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

to

`/usr/bin/xterm`

Why does`sudo su -` still try to execute terminator ? How can I debug this problem ?

Comment: Does anything in root's `.bashrc`, `.profile` etc. launch a terminal? What about `sudo bash -lx`?

Comment: .bashrc and .profile don't contain the string "terminal"

what am I lookingn for in sudo bash -lx ? can't grep it ?!

Comment: `sudo bash -lx` runs a bash with each command it runs printed to stderr, IIRC. If the error came, you should be able to spot it, even so.

Comment: What does `cat /etc/passwd | grep root` say? (This won't reveal your root password hash; the file doesn't contain password information, despite the name)

Comment: You should be using `sudo -i` anyhow, right?

Comment: @mchid:    `sudo -i` gave me the same result

Comment: @the_Seppi: thank you ! root was using    `/usr/bin/terminator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `/usr/bin/terminator` set as the default shell for root (see comments). You can change it back to whatever shell you like with the following command:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

Should `sudo` not work either, you can follow this procedure to fix it (assuming you are using GRUB):

1. Reboot
2. If the boot menu doesn't show up automatically, reboot and repeatedly hit <kbd>↑ Shift</kbd> until it appears.
3. In the boot menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the entry.
4. Navigate to the end of the line similar to

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-... quiet splash
   ```
5. Replace `quiet splash` by `init=/bin/bash` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot the modified entry. You will be dropped to a root shell.
6. Remount your root filesystem writable with `mount -o rw,remount /`.
7. Change the default shell of root back to e.g. BASH with `chsh -s /bin/bash root`.
8. Reboot with `reboot`.

Comment: The solution is much simpler. Open `/etc/passwd` either with [vipw](http://linuxg.net/how-to-safely-edit-etcpasswd-etcshadow-and-etcgroup-in-linux/) or vim and replace `/usr/bin/terminator` with `/usr/bin/bash` or whatever shell you prefer.

Comment: And how would you do so without being able to su?

Comment: The command `sudo` worked, but `sudo su` didn't, because it switches to another user. In my case I wanted to switch to user root, but root was using a shell,  which I had deinstalled.

Comment: I updated my answer, but left the GRUB route as is, in case other people may find it useful.